# Running methods generated by AntLR 4 grammar

Tags: java, antlr4, antlr3

I found [a project [GitHub]](https://github.com/nitinmesta/java-date-parser) to parse the natural date string and show the appropriate Date value. I wanted to modify the grammar according to my need and I did to some extent. But when I tried to run the required methods I am getting the below error:

> ANTLR Tool version 4.4 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5ANTLR Tool version 4.4 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5 null

The original project used AntLR3 to generate the Java source code and I am using ANTLR 4 plugin to generate the source code.

I have placed the Antlr 4.5 complete JAR in my *lib* directory. Post this error I copied the 4.4 jar into *lib*. Even then no luck.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, please post the solution as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I could resolve this. I removed the jar 4.5 from lib folder and it worked for me!!

Comment: Thanks for following up. Now it is a comment :-) still not an answer...

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above the problem was the presence of an ANTLR4.5 jar in the lib folder.  Removing the jar file fixed the issue.  Posting as answered.